# MySQL FULL JOIN not working but RIGHT and LEFT join works

Tags: mysql, join, full-outer-join

This is driving me nuts.  I have two tables that I am attempting to preform a join on, usersXstats and usersXstats_alltime.

Both tables have the same columns: id, userId, statId, and value

What I am trying to do is

```
SELECT * 
FROM usersXstats 
FULL JOIN usersXstats_alltime 
ON usersXstats.userId=usersXstats_alltime.userId 
AND usersXstats.statId=usersXstats_alltime.statId
```

However this is returning

```
Unknown column 'usersXstats.userId' in 'on clause'
```

This query works just as expected when replacing FULL JOIN with LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, or INNER JOIN.

To make it easier to read initially I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usersXstats as uxs 
FULL JOIN usersXstats_alltime as uxsat 
ON uxs.userId=uxsat.userId 
AND uxs.statId=uxsat.statId
```

Which returned a different error:

`check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN usersXstats_alltime as uxsat ON uxs.userId=uxsat.userId AND uxs.statId' at line 1`

What on earth am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support FULL JOIN

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join

Comment: Replacing FULL JOIN with FULL OUTER JOIN returns the error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN usersXstats_alltime
ON usersXstats.userId=usersXstats_alltime.userId ' at line 1

Comment: Read the full section in the link, a MySQL solution is provided.

Comment: Oh, stupid me didn't read far enough.  I thought the first example was MySQL.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this [How to simulate FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/).
It may helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the results I wanted using UNION, however doesn't this seem a bit messy?  Shouldn't I be able to do this with a full outer join?

Comment: Nevermind.  I guess MySQL doesn't support FULL JOIN.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please add the infos to your post in case when the link dies

Answer (score 1):

**FULL OUTER JOIN** won't support in mysql.

You can emulate **FULL OUTER JOIN** using **UNION** (from MySQL 4.0.0 on):

with two tables usersXstats,usersXstats_alltime

```
SELECT * FROM usersXstats
LEFT JOIN usersXstats_alltime ON usersXstats.userId= usersXstats_alltime.userId
UNION
SELECT * FROM usersXstats
RIGHT JOIN usersXstats_alltime ON usersXstats.statId= usersXstats_alltime.statId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Person1.Firstname, Person2.State
FROM Person1
left JOIN Person2
ON Person1.PersonID=Person2.PersonID
UNION
SELECT Person1.Firstname, Person2.State
FROM Person1
right JOIN Person2
ON Person1.PersonID=Person2.PersonID;
```

is working superbly.

Comment: Hi Rajesh - if you add 4 spaces to the start of each line in the code then it will be properly formatted as a code block :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is but I was facing the same issue so here you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usersXstats 
Left JOIN usersXstats_alltime 
ON usersXstats.userId=usersXstats_alltime.userId
Union
SELECT * 
FROM usersXstats 
RightJOIN usersXstats_alltime 
ON usersXstats.userId=usersXstats_alltime.userId
```

Comment: Welcomo to SO. You answer equal to other already given. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8950981/1138946.